# Git untracked files

Tags: git

I recently added .gitignore to the project, in order to make it work, I used `git rm --cached` to remove redundant files, but when I checked with `git status`, I found that these files are actually untracked, I want to know why they are untracked files and not tracked files.

--Update--

I know these files should not be added to git, maybe I am not clear, because I added gitignore later, so I want to remove git's control of these files now, but after removal they become untracked , but some files are staged and marked as delete, so I just wonder why only these files become untracked after I use `git rm --cached`.

.gitignore

```
# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Log/OS Files
*.log

# Android Studio generated files and folders
app/build/
app/release/
captures/
.externalNativeBuild/
.cxx/
*.apk
output.json

# IntelliJ
*.iml
.idea/
misc.xml
deploymentTargetDropDown.xml
render.experimental.xml

# Keystore files
*.jks
*.keystore

# Google Services (e.g. APIs or Firebase)
google-services.json

# Android Profiling
*.hprof
```

[image]

Comment: You don't really want to track build outputs or .gradle or .idea anyway. Are those in your .gitignore? Can you show the . gitignore please?

Comment: as @ndc85430 said, seems like those files/folders should be untracked and are probably untracked because they are in .gitignore. Why do you think/want them to be tracked?

Comment: I know these files should not be added to git, maybe I am not clear, because I added gitignore later, so I want to remove git's control of these files now, but after removal they become untracked , but some files are staged and marked as delete, so I just wonder why only these files become untracked after I use git rm --cached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any folder with generated content should not be versioned.

If you edit your `.gitignore` and add rules like [`github/gitignore/Android.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Android.gitignore), those untracked files should becomes "ignored".

That means there should not be listed anymore in your `git status`.

In [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245843/discussion-between-vonc-and-joe199382), the OP confirms having environment variables starting with `GIT_`.

If those are "[repository location](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_repository_locations)" `GIT_DIR` or `GIT_WORK_TREE`, that would explain why the `.gitignore` *appears* to be not working.
The git status would be executed actually against another repository location, even when done in the folder with said `.gitignore`.

Comment: I know these files should not be added to git, maybe I am not clear, because I added gitignore later, so I want to remove git's control of these files now, but after removal they become untracked , but some files are staged and marked as delete, so I just wonder why only these files become untracked after I use git rm --cached

Comment: @Joe199382 That's because your .gitignore did not involve those files. Or was placed in a subfolder too low. rm --cached alone is not enough. Your rules should include those files/folder you don't want to see.

Comment: Best to place .gitignore file in root of your repository.

Comment: My rules match them, most of the files are ignored, only the files in the picture are not ignored

Comment: @Joe199382 You can check if you rules match them with `git check-ignore -v -- path/to/file`, from the folder where your `.gitignore` is. So it depends on where your `.gitignore` is.

Comment: @VonC Thanks a lot for your help, I checked and they are in compliance with the rules.

Comment: @Joe199382 Do you mean the `git check-ignore` command shows you a gitignore rule? Or does it return nothing?

Comment: Yes, I used this command and they are in compliance with the rules.

Comment: @Joe199382 If the command returns a `gitignore` rule, then git status should not show you those as untracked.

Comment: That's exactly why I'm confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245843/discussion-between-vonc-and-joe199382).